# How to find interface type based on a couple of field values and be able to then create an object with that interface's list of fields

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have a complicated problem that I'm not sure how best to code in typescript. Or I am making it complicated. I was trying to stay away from creating a class for each one of the interfaces below (and there are a lot more than these in what I'm trying to address (about 6 workflows, and 4 steps). I'm totally open for a better way to do this.
The problem is: I have several workflows each of them having several steps using different fields for each. Let's conceptualize this with interfaces and types as follow so it's clearer.
My main issue is that saveFirstStepInfo doesn't work as is since I don't know how to save the fields into an object of that interface type. I guess I could save fields in a map, but then I would have to save several maps for each of the steps for one workflow so saving as an object seemed better and each of the step objects for one workflow type would be a member variable of the WorkflowRequest class as shown below:

```
private workflowFirstStep: FirstStep;
private workflowSecondStep: SecondStep;
```

file name: workflowType.ts

```
export interface FirstStepWorkflowA {
  type: 'workflowA',
  step: 'first',
  name: string,
  description: string,
  price: number
}

export interface SecondStepWorkflowA {
  type: 'workflowA'
  step: 'second',
  name: string;
  price: number
  taxes: number;
  finalPrice: number;
}

export interface FirstStepWorkflowB {
   type: 'workflowB',
   step: 'first',
   name: string,
   components: string[],
   prices: number[]
}

export interface SecondStepWorkflowB {
   type: 'workflowB',
   step: 'second',
   name: string,
   prices: number[],
   totalPrice: number
}
export type FirstStep = FirstStepWorkflowA | FirstStepWorkflowB;
export type SecondStep = SecondStepWorkflowA | SecondStepWorkflowB;
export type WorkflowType = FirstStep | SecondStep;

export getFieldList = (type, step ): Array<string> => {
   let fieldArray: Array<string>;
   if (step === 'first') && (type === 'workflowA') {
       fieldArray = Array<keyof FirstStepWorkflowA>();
   } else if (step === 'second') && (type === 'workflowA') {
       fieldArray = Array<keyof SecondStepWorkflowA>();
   } else if... and so forth

   return fieldArray;
}

export getWorkflowObject(workflow: string, step: string): WorkflowType => {
   let workflowType: WorkflowType;
   ?
   return workflowType;
}
```

Now I want to be able to record field values from the UI based on the list of fields defined by the interface and store that object in a WorkflowRequest class.
And there is a RequestList class, that stores an ordered list of WorkflowRequest
The WorkflowRequest class would have those workflowStep objects as members.

```
import { workflowType } from 'workflowType';
export default class WorkflowRequest {
   private workflowType: string;
   private workflowFirstStep: FirstStep;
   private workflowSecondStep: SecondStep;
   constructor(workflowType: string) {this.workflowType = workflowType}
   public setWorkflowFirstStep(firstStep: WorkflowFirstStep) {
      this.workflowFirstStep = firstStep;
   }
}
```

And then I would store the values

```
    const arrayOfValuesFromUI1 = ['phone', 'iphoneSE', '200'];
    const arrayOfValuesFromUI2 = ['phone', '200', '16', '216'];
    public saveFirstStepInfo(workflow: string, step: string): void {
            const workflowRequest = new WorkflowRequest(workflow);
            const fields: Array<string> = getFieldArray(workflow, step);
            // Starting at 2 because field 0 is workflow and field 1 is step.

            let i = 2;
            for (let j=0; j<arrayOfValuesFromUI1.length; j++) {
                workflowType.fields[i] = arrayOfValuesFromUI1[j] ;
                i++;
            });
            
            workflowRequest.setWorkflowFirstStep(workflowType);
        });
    }
```

saveFirstStepInfo should work whether arrayOfValuesFromUI1 is used or arrayOfValuesFromUI2 is used since when I get values from the UI, the array will be different and will correspond to the fields in the different interface.
In other words, I want to avoid having to have a method specific for each workflow to store the UI values since UI elements are the same, but only the fields differ. My question is mainly: I'm not sure

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs.  Pseudocode or external/private dependencies should be replaced with valid code and relevant declarations. Ideally the only issues present should be ones you're asking about.

Comment: I removed the cypress specific part and replaced by a basic array. May be I'm complicating things too much and there is a much simplier way to handle that

Comment: Your code is largely still pseudocode so I'm not inclined to do much with it.  Code problems unrelated to your question are a disincentive.   It looks like you want to be able to convert between an array of stringified field values and an object holding those values, but an [mre] of desired input/output pairs would be helpful here.